# how to handle file upload case in ubuntu machine using selenium with java

Tags: selenium

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='invoiceUploadButton mat-elevation-z1 fileBrowseContainer']")).click();
```

with this i am able to click on choose file button to upload file.But after it i have a window pop-up to upload respective file. How to upload my file here? It works only in windows machine.

HTML Dom reference

```html
<div class="invoiceUploadButton mat-elevation-z1 fileBrowseContainer"> 
   <span>Choose File</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It will helpful if you provide the Html DOM code.There are two types of file upload one type is from normal `input` tag and another one is handled from js need your code sample to justify which type of file upload it is

Comment: File Upload is working with javascript. Also post the respective js code.If you can't find it seek the help from developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `sendKeys` method to provide the file path and then hit the Upload or Ok button.

```java
addFile.sendKeys("D:\Big Data on AWS\Images\caps.jpeg");
driver.findElement(//Upload button).click();
```